# Mouse pointer disappears in web browser

Tags: mouse, web-browser

I have this issue and from what I discovered a lot other people do - my pointer disappears. I can see stuff beneath reacting to the movement, but the pointer is gone. It happens rarely, but is confusing enough. Cmd + Tab to Finder fixes the issue, but then when going back to the browser, the pointer is gone again.

It mostly happens in Safari and Chrome. I haven't seen any solution that works.

I'm using OS X 10.8, but this problem existed before that too.

Comment: Do you have always the same web sites open when it happens?

Comment: no, but some of the sites are similar, my gmail is always open.

Comment: If it only happens in the browser it's most probably coming from something happening inside it -> JavaScript running in a window/tab or browser extensions. If the sites are different I would proceed the analysis by disabling all extensions for a few days to see if the problem goes away then.

Comment: I don't use any extensions (except for AdBlock)